# How to browse pdf file from my iphone for my app, just like I am able to browse pdf file through ibooks?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios12

Just like browsing UIIMage using `UIImagePickerViewController`. Is there any way to browse Another files in Swift / objective code?

```
if let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyImage", withExtension: "jpg") {
            // Instantiate the interaction controller
            self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileURL)
        }
        else {
            shareButton.enabled = false
            print("File missing! Button has been disabled")
        }
```

Comment: @R.yan: regarding your edit, please do not add please-help pleading to people's questions. It does not aid readability at all, and is not the technical writing we aim for here.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access files in document folder. To access All the files

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
do {
    let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    // process files
} catch {
    print("Error while enumerating files \(documentsURL.path): \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

and if you want to single file look following code:

```
// Get the document directory url
let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

do {
    // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    print(directoryContents)

    // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
    let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }
    print("mp3 urls:",mp3Files)
    let mp3FileNames = mp3Files.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
    print("mp3 list:", mp3FileNames)

} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: is there any way to access that document folder?
by this code I will jus t be be able to get the file names . Can I Access those file in my app?. Please help

Comment: you can use first code to see all the file in your document directory and if you have that pdf in document directory definitely you can access them.

Comment: The code i am  asking for is to fetch /get access of  PDF from . Phone's directory not from apps internal directory of my app.. i wish to get access of pdf listed in Ibook . just like We browse pdf file in WhatsApp

Answer (score -1):

If you want to view PDF files within your app there are two ways.

**PDFView** - available iOS 11.0

```
let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url)
pdfView.document = pdfDocument
```

**WKWebView** - available iOS 8.0

```
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest.init(url: url))
```

You could also use UIWebview to get the same result, But it has been deprecated.

Alternatively, use a file explorer library that you can customize to what you need done. Something like [this](https://github.com/Augustyniak/FileExplorer)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

Comment: The code i am  asking for is to fetch /get access of  PDF from . Phone's directory not from apps internal directory of my app.. i wish get access of pdf listed in Ibook . just like We browse pdf file in WhatsApp